# Handling JSON Parsing Error in Node.js Stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, stream

I'm working on a small simple Node.js project that I expect to autonomously work with a public-facing API and my mongoDB server. For the most part everything is working smoothly and I don't expect any problem hitting the API once an hour.

However, there are times which instead of returning the body of data the API returns a JSON-formatted error statement (see below). In these cases `JSON.parse(data)` throws an exception because the format is already in JSON (and not the buffered bytes expected). Since this is a portfolio piece and others will be looking at the code, I want to be as prepared as possible for conditions I can't foresee overtime but haven't found a good way of approaching the parsing problem yet.

At first I had assumed that `.on("error", ... )` would handle this error but I guess because it's the JSON parser and not the stream which catches the exception it will have to be handled there. I'm happy to just break out of `readStream` and get the data next hour but haven't found a configuration of `try/catch` that will do this. What are some ways to handle this exception so that it doesn't crash the server?

```
function readStream(stream) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let saved = [];
        stream
            .on('data', function (data) {
                console.log('Debug | readStream data: ', data); //See Output Below
                const json = JSON.parse(data); // Exception here Line 37
                saved.push(json.data);
                if (saved.length > 4) {
                    stream.destroy();
                }
            })
            .on('close', () => {
                resolve(saved);
            })
            .on('error', (error) => reject(error))
            .on('timeout', (error) => reject(error));
    });
}

// API sometimes returns
{
  title: 'ConnectionException',
  detail: 'This stream is currently at the maximum allowed connection limit.',
  connection_issue: 'TooManyConnections',
  type: URL
}

//Exception Text from console
undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at PassThrough.<anonymous> (/Users/?????/Documents/JavaScript-Projects/website-dashbaord1-nodejs/src/API.js:37:23)
```

Comment: `URL` in your API return is not a valid `JSON` - i believe thats why you are getting that error.

Comment: A try catch block within the `'data'` handler should catch that SyntaxError. You could reject from there, or provide alternate behavior.

Comment: the `on('error'` handler gets called for stream errors, not your codes errors ... `on('data'` may get called more than once ... you should combine the data into some sort of buffer in the `data` handler, and parse it in `on('end'` - see [this sample code](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end)